# trying to solve dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I have a problem from a contest which is already over. Below is  the Question .

In Poornima college, PIET CS Deparment is shifting from basement to the third floor. The HOD of the department is trying to finding the number ways to reach the third floor. You are given the number of stairs, and you have to help HOD to find out number of ways in which he can climb the stairs. The HOD is capable of climb maximum two stairs at a time and minimum zero.

```
Input:The first line contains the number of test cases, T. 
T lines follow, each of which contains total number of stairs.

Output:
Print the total number of possible ways to climbing the stairs.

Constraints: 
1<=T<=100
1<=N<=100

Sample Input(Plaintext Link)
 3
1
2
4
Sample Output(Plaintext Link)
 1
2
5
Explanation
Input: n = 1
Output: 1
There is only one way to climb 1 stair

Input: n = 2
Output: 2
There are two ways: (1, 1) and (2,0)

Input: n = 4
Output: 5
(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2,0), (2, 1, 1,0), (1, 2, 1,0), (2, 2,0,0) are the only four ways to climb stairs.
```

i am sure the solution can be achieved by using DP. but i tried and failed i am new to solving DP problems.how can i solve it?

here is one solution but how is that DP formula derived?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

#define LL long long int
#define s(a) scanf("%d",&a)

#define ss(a) scanf("%s",a)
#define w(t) while(t--)
#define f(i,n) for(i=0;i<n;i++)
#define fd(i,n) for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
#define p(a) printf("%d",a)

#define ps(a) printf("%s",a)
#define pc(a) printf("%c",a)
#define ent printf("\n")
bool wayToSort(int i, int j) { return i > j; }
using namespace std;
long long int dp[1005];
int main()
{   dp[0]=0;
    dp[1]=1;
    dp[2]=2;
    int t,i,j,n;
    for(i=3;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=dp[i-1]+dp[i-2];
    }
    s(t);
    w(t)
    {
        s(n);
        cout<<dp[n]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask your question here rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: What is the purpose of defining loops or functions like these, thus making the program unreadable ?

Comment: @Blacktempel This is purely for  a competition where even a sec late matters a lot so just for speed purpose its defined so.

Comment: @HardeosinghSingh Does [compile speed](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) matter in a competition ?

Comment: @Blacktempel no only the execution time of the program

Comment: @HardeosinghSingh What makes you think `#define` as preprocessor directive could speed that up ? All you get here is a unreadable program. No speed increases at all.

Comment: @Blacktempel speed in terms of writing a program . once we get the solution its foolish to type long loops and some functions again and again so . that is not the problem actually what i want is logic to solve it using DP   . i knows its a bad code but as i mentioned its for **PROGRAMMING COMPETITION**

Comment: I think there goes no time in typing if you know what you have to type... I am irritated with these types of #defines which make the program unreadable... Infacf it makes the program unreadable!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma anyone with a very basic knowledge of the language can read it very fluently. guess you need to participate once in such a competition to know its benefit. anyway thanks for criticism. can i repeat it once more its for a competition not a software project that is maintained by group of people. i am tired of explaining

Comment: No problem if you type it for competition but you posted it here. I was suggesting rather than criticising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a very general dynamic programming puzzle... Assume you are at the n th stair, then the number of ways you can go to the n th stair is number of ways to reach n-1 th stair and n th stair! 
Why?
Well , I can reach to the n th stair in only two ways from the n-1th stair climbing one stair and from n-2 th stair climbing two directly!

Morover I feel a problem with your problem statement,it says we can at minimum can move 0 steps that will cause the number of ways to reach some stair infinite! Why? I can simply use infinite steps to stay on the same stair and then move for the next one ! So i have assumed that you can move one or two stair at a time